# Can't add Global.asax to ASP.Net MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok, so here's the issue. I get a HTTP Error 403.14 (Forbidden) error when I build and run my MVC application because instead of loading the default page (which is at /Views/Home/Index.cshtml). I suspect this is because the Global.asax file is missing from my application...however adding it back in doesn't help.

When I add the global.asax ("Add Global Application Class") it adds the web forms version to my project, which isn't helpful. Altering it to look like a normal MVC global.asax file simply gives me a "Cannot load Namespace.MvcApplication" error (none of the fixes on this site work for helping with that).

I'm just running the site on my local machine through Visual Studio and the app compiles successfully, as far as I can tell.

Something has gone weirdly wrong and I haven't the faintest clue what to do about it.

Comment: How did it dissapear in the first place?

Comment: Not sure, tbh, I assume somebody mistakenly deleted it? I've seen that happen before - added global.asax (overwriting the existing one) to do something, decided not to do it and so deleted it - checking that removal into TFS :( (I can't find the original in TFS).

Comment: Ok, so I rescued this from TFS (found it eventually), however I'm still interested in how you would solve this normally. I'll keep an eye on this and mark any appropriate answer as correct.

Comment: in new global.asax file do you registered routes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create an empty new project. Then copy the structure exactly as it it appears in the default new project. Hopefully that will get you back to a good starting point.

Comment: I had considered this, but the solution is source controlled, so this would be a massive pain in the ass. I might try it anyway and see how I go.

Comment: You should only need to copy the one file though. To your original project from the newly created one

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean, I'll try this and let you know if it works (tomorrow).